# Sorting an Array without changing it C

Tags: arrays, arduino, sorting

Hey guys I have been working on this for 3 days and have come up with nothing from everywere I have looked.

I am trying to take an Array of around 250 floats and find the Kth largest value without changing the array in anyway or making a new array.

I can change it or create a new one because other functions need the placing of the data in the correct order and my Arduino cant hold any more values in its memory space so the 2 easiest options are out.

The values in the Array can ( and probably will ) have duplicates in them.

As an EG : if you have the array :::  1,36,2,54,11,9,22,9,1,36,0,11;
from Max to min would be :: 
1) 54
2) 36
3) 36
4) 22
5) 11
6) 11
7) 9
8) 9
9) 2
10) 1 
11) 1
12) 0

Any help would be great.
It may be to much to ask for a function that would do this nicely for me :) hahaha

here is the code I have so far but I have not even tried to get the duplicates working yet 
and it for some reason only gives me one answer for some reason that's 2 ,,, no clue why though

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop ()
{
 int Array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

 int Kth = 6; //// just for testing putting the value as a constant
 int tr = 0;   /// traking threw the array to find the MAX

 for (int y=0;y<10;y++)  ////////////  finding the MAX first so I have somewhere to start
 {
   if (Array[y]>Array[tr])
   {
     tr = y;
   }
 }
 Serial.print("The max number is ");
 int F = Array[tr];
 Serial.println(F); // Prints the MAX ,,, mostly just for error checking this is done

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  got MAX

 for ( int x = 1; x<Kth;x++)  //// run the below Kth times and each time lowering the "Max" making the loop run Kth times
 {
   for(int P=0;P<10;P++) // run threw every element
   {
   if (Array[P]<F)
   {
     for(int r=0;r<10;r++)    //and then test that element against every other element to make sure 
                             //its is bigger then all the rest but small then MAX
     {
       Serial.println(r);
       if(r=tr)  /////////////////// done so the max dosent clash with the number being tested
       {
       r++;
       Serial.println("Max's Placeing !!!!");
       }
     if(Array[P]>Array[r])
     {
       F=Array[P];            ////// if its bigger then all others and smaller then the MAx then make that the Max
       Serial.print(F);
       Serial.println(" on the ");
     }
}}}}
Serial.println(F); /// ment to give me the Kth largest number 
delay(1000);
```

}

Comment: Is an array the size of K an option?

Answer (score 1):

If speed isn't an issue you can take this approach (pseudocode):

```
current=inf,0

for i in [0,k):
    max=-inf,0
    for j in [0,n):
        item=x[j],j
        if item<current and item>max:
          max=item
    current=max
```

`current` will then contain the kth largest item, where an item is a pair of value and index.

The idea is simple.  To find the first largest item, you just find the largest item.  To find the second largest item, you find the largest item that isn't greater than your first largest item.  To find the third largest item, you find the largest item that isn't greater than your second largest item.  etc.

The only trick here is that since there can be duplicates, the items need to include both a value and an index to make them unique.

Here is how it might be implemented in C:

```
void loop()
{
  int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int n = 10;
  int k = 6; //// just for testing putting the value as a constant
  int c = n; // start with current index being past the end of the array
             // to indicate that there is no current index. 

  for (int x = 1; x<=k; x++) {
    int m = -1; // start with the max index being before the beginning of
                // the array to indicate there is no max index

    for (int p=0; p<n; p++) {
      int ap = array[p];
      // if this item is less than current
      if (c==n || ap<array[c] || (ap==array[c] && p<c)) {
        // if this item is greater than max
        if (m<0 || ap>array[m] || (ap==array[m] && p>m)) {
          // make this item be the new max
          m = p;
        }
      }
    }
    // update current to be the max
    c = m;
  }
  Serial.println(array[c]); /// ment to give me the Kth largest number 
  delay(1000);
}
```

In the C version, I just keep track of the current and max indices, since I can always get the current and max values by looking in the array.

Comment: That's the idea I was going for but wasn't able to pull it off ..... mind telling me what is going on above ? tried to get a bearing on that but did not understand your variables ,,, what language are you writing that in ? because unfortunately I'm not understanding that too well thanks man

Comment: @Spider999: I've added a C implementation.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much :) will run over in in the morning when I get a bit of time thanks again